# Unity3d Delete current picture showing in gallery

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm fairly new to C# and Unity so I'm having a little issue here. I'm working on some kind of "photobooth app", which makes the gallery a big part of it. However, I managed to sort out the part of taking screenshots and show them, my problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to delete the pictures from the gallery (I mean, inside the app).

So far, I'm working with this code (just to give it some sense), but this bit erases ALL of the taken pictures, not just the one currently showing.

```
tring path = Application.persistentDataPath;

    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    FileInfo[] info = dir.GetFiles("*.png");

    foreach (FileInfo f in info)
    {
        File.Delete(f.FullName);
    }
```

I don't know if it'd help, but this is the code I'm using to take and save the screenshots:

```
 yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    string timeStamp = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss");
    string fileName = "Screenshot" + timeStamp + ".png";
    string pathToSave = fileName;
    ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot(pathToSave);
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
```

And, the one I'm using for showing them in the gallery:

```
   public class ScreenShotPreview : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    GameObject Panel;
    [SerializeField]
    string sceneName;

string[] files = null;
int whichScreenShotIsShown = 0;

void Start()
{

    files = Directory.GetFiles(Application.persistentDataPath + "/", "*.png");
    if (files.Length > 0)
    {
        GetPictureAndShowIt();
    }
}

void GetPictureAndShowIt()
{
    string pathToFile = files[whichScreenShotIsShown];
    Texture2D texture = GetScreenshotImage(pathToFile);
    Sprite sp = Sprite.Create(texture, new Rect(0, 0, texture.width, texture.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));
    Panel.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = sp;
}

Texture2D GetScreenshotImage(string filePath)
{
    Texture2D texture = null;
    byte[] fileBytes;
    if (File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        texture = new Texture2D(2, 2, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
        texture.LoadImage(fileBytes);
    }
    return texture;
}

public void NextPicture()
{
    if (files.Length > 0)
    {
        whichScreenShotIsShown += 1;
        if (whichScreenShotIsShown > files.Length - 1)
            whichScreenShotIsShown = 0;
        GetPictureAndShowIt();
    }
}

public void PreviousPicture()
{
    if (files.Length > 0)
    {
        whichScreenShotIsShown -= 1;
        if (whichScreenShotIsShown < 0)
            whichScreenShotIsShown = files.Length - 1;
        GetPictureAndShowIt();
    }
}
```

I hope it makes sense? Thank you in advance!

TLDR; Can't figure out how to delete current picture showing in the gallery.

Comment: Can you show the code where you try to delete the specific images being shown? You have showed us the code for the deletion-code (that removes everything) but where are you calling it from

Comment: As I said, I'm not very sure of how to implement the code, so I'm just working around it at this point.

I'm editing the post to add it anyway, thanks.

Comment: You need to know the filenames of the images you want to delete. Im guessing you can produce a list of them somehow? Then, in your deletion-code you need to only delete only these.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. You mean, looking through all the saved pictures names and then delete the specific path, right? Hmm. Okay, I think I could look into that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file paths are stored in the `string[] files` variable. The `whichScreenShotIsShown` variable is the current index that determines which path is currently being displayed. These two variables are declared inside the `ScreenShotPreview`  script.

Therefore to delete the current file, you would do something like this:

```
string currentFile = files[whichScreenShotIsShown];
File.Delete(currentFile );
```